# How to write a program to get minimum, maximum and average of values

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

int sum = 0; 
int inputNum;
int counter;
float average;
double Max = 0; 
double Min = 101;      

Scanner NumScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner charScanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
System.out.println("Enter the total number of exams you want a average");
counter = NumScanner.nextInt();
System.out.println("Please enter " + counter + " numbers:");

for(int i = 1; i<=counter ;i++){          
    inputNum = NumScanner.nextInt();
    sum = sum + inputNum;
    System.out.println();

    if(inputNum > Max){
        Max = inputNum;
    }
    if(inputNum < Min){
        Min = inputNum;
    }
    if(inputNum > -1 && inputNum < 101){
        sum = sum + inputNum;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("You entered a number that wasn't in the range of 0 to 100");
        average = sum / counter;
    }
    }
}
}
```

Write a program using a loop that takes 10 values from a user representing exam grades (between 0 and 100) from the keyboard and outputs the minimum value, maximum value and average value of all the values entered.  Your program should not accept values less than 0 or greater than 100. Problems with calculation of average and the program does not print out max and min values

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the point of having two Scanners?

Comment: Tip 1: use indentation that shows the structure of your code.

Comment: Well where do you need help? What did you try? Where is the exception? What according you is where you are stuck at? To avoid these questions you should refine your question.

Comment: The way the program is now I can't get an average of numbers the user enters. If I take the out the IF Else statements the average can be calculated. Also I need to print out the max and min values the user enters.

Comment: I have tried a lot of different things just to get to this point in the program.

Comment: You have a max-variable that is lower than your min-variable, you create two scanners from the same input stream, you name one of your scanners with a capital letter, you don't use your Min and Max-variables to anything, if inputNum > -1 && inputNum < 100 you add inputNum to your sum twice... and your undentation of your code is bad. Go do some tutorials on java first, the problem is your base programming skills.

Comment: Tip 2: the sanity check of the input (0 to 100) should be the first thing you do in the loop.

Comment: Tip 3: doing `sum = sum + inputNum;` twice will lead to a wrong sum and average.

Comment: Thanks Henry I didn't catch that mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//This code is how to print out the max and min values of a list of numbers from the above program//

```
// Print out of max and min exam grades//
    System.out.println( "Max Exam Score = " + Max );
    System.out.println( "Minimum Exam Score = " + Min `enter code here`);
```